# XSLT 2.0 tokenising delimiters within delimiters

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In XSLT 2.0 I have long string (parameter) with a delimiter (;) inside a delimiter (~), more specifically a triplet inside a delimiter.

Data is organized like so:

`<parameter>qrsbfs;qsvsv;tfgz~dknk;fvtea;gtvath~pksdi;ytbdi;oiunhu</parameter>`

The first `tokenize($mystring,'~')` in a `for-each` produces :

```
qrsbfs;qsvsv;tfgz
dknk;fvtea;gtvath
pksdi;ytbdi;oiunhu
```

Within that tokenization,  I need to treat it by looping again:

```
qrsbfs
qsvsv
tfgz

dknk
fvtea
gtvath

pksdi
ytbdi
oiunhu
```

I can do intensive string manipulation to get there using `concat`, `string-length`, and `substring-before`/`substring-after`, but I wondered if there wasn't a more elegant solution that my neophyte mind wasn't overlooking?

EDIT, adding nested tokenize that returned incorrect results:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($myparameter,'~')">
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,';')">
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position()=2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position()=3">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Why can't you use `tokenize(., ';')` inside the first `for-each`? But if all that is from your previous attempt to pass data from XQuery to XSLT then I wonder why you don't build the XSLT/XPath strings or XML data with the necessary tokens directly.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  For your first question, I tried to tokenize inside tokenize for-loop and it errored out. I've added the code above. As for your second question, I simply saw the parameter as a string. I have no better answer than one from years of working with SQL and strictly delimited files. Now I'm considering how to pass dynamically constructed XML in a parameter, without having to create an actual document in a file.

Comment: I've misunderstood your final question. The fragment I need in XSLT could be built in the Xquery process. The XSLT itself is outputting javascript so I'm having to think in deeply nested fashion. But you're right to force me to rethink that. Admittedly I'm not inclined to fragment code, and prefer separating construction of final output from the data that moves around in the application. Thanks for this important challenge to my thinking.

Comment: So what do you want to have as the returned value, is that a sequence of strings or plain text with those chunks you have shown?

Comment: Simply put, a sequence of strings. More to my point of why I don't want to construct the tokens in Xquery: the target is javascript, and I moved the output to XSLT to avoid having to escape a variety of characters such as { } in the first place.

Comment: Which sequence of strings exactly does that chunk in your wanted result represent, is that one string item per line?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a one line solution, you could do something like this, using nested for-in-return statements:

```
 <xsl:sequence select="for $n in tokenize(.,'~') return concat(string-join(tokenize($n,';'),'&#xa;'),'&#xa;&#xa;')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to tokenize them separately, you could replace the `~` with `;` and tokenize all 9 elements at the same time:

`tokenize(replace(parameter,'~',';'),';')`

Comment: Each string within the groups of three needs to be treated differently on final output (to another code). I can't usefully use a long list.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the code in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUe uses

```
  <xsl:template match="parameter">
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '~')">
          <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ';')" separator="&#10;"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

and with output method `text` produces

```
qrsbfs
qsvsv
tfgz

dknk
fvtea
gtvath

pksdi
ytbdi
oiunhu
```